# Как изменить внешний вид отображения записей на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как изменить внешний вид отображения записей на WordPress? У меня стоит тема OceanWP, в "Настроить" я не нашел то, чем можно изменить внешний вид и начал менять его через CSS. Но у меня возник вопрос. Есть ли плагин который позволяет легко и быстро сделать это? Ну для того чтобы не менять все самому, а сделать это быстрее с плагином. Если это можно изменить в "Настроить", прошу, скажите где конкретно. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как бы там даже в картинках показывают где и что меняется. https://oceanwp.org/oceanwp-features/

Answer (score 0):

Все современные темы, а к ним и Ocean WP относится, используют кастомайзер. В админке "Внешний вид->Настроить".